# Associate Products to Categories after Export CSV

Tags: magento-1.7, category, import, configurable-product, export

Is there a way to associate products with categories?

I've exported a csv with all the products, images etc (a complete export) then after the import (it wasn't painless) I've noticed 3 things

1) Categories was missing! Removed the products. Uploaded a csv with the categories. Uploaded, again, products but they still not in categories!!!

Do you know a way I can associate those products with categories?

Possibly with a csv? I've tried [this](http://www.meteorify.com/2012/05/importing-product-images-via-csv-in-magento-1-7-0-0/) (changing it a bit) and read other stuff on the net but no luck.

-

2) Configurable products are not associated, different colors and sizes products are there but not associated with the main product... (didn't fixed it yet)

3) Images was missing in Back & Frond end. fixed. (it wasn't painless)

Answer (score 2):

To associate products with categories in Dataflow you'll need two pieces of data:

- Sku (Configurable, Simple, doesn't matter)
- The target Category IDs

The field for the category IDs needs to be comma-separated itself, so make sure it's quoted if you're manually creating it:

```
sku,category_ids
ABCD1234,"1,2,3,4,5"
L0S7,"4,8,15,16,23,42"
```

Save it to disk as a .csv file, and you can upload it to the All Products Import default dataflow profile. **This will replace all current categories for the skus listed**, so take caution and make sure to get a list of pre-existing category associations.

Comment: thanks .. but here comes the problem.. magento export isn't working. So I'm using a external script to export products and the other data, and this script exports categories in some strange format (json) example: [[3,1\/3,Root Catalog],[3,1\/3,Root Catalog]]

Comment: is there some way I can export only sku and categories in a csv file?

Answer (score 2):

Have you used Magmi by any chance? It makes uploading to Magento a lot easier (as well as configurable products). It may solve some of your problems (such as the configurable products, images, categories).

It is also very, very quick.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/

Give it a shot. I swear by it. :)